# Calculate compounded annual growth rates

Tags: stata

I have a panel dataset with values of companies between 2006-2015.

This looks something like the example below:

[image: Example]

I want to calculate three-year compounded annual growth rates:

- 2006-2009
- 2007-2010
- ...
- 2012-2015

I have already tried to use the following command:

```
bys tina: generate SalesGrowth=(Sales/L3.Sales)^(1/3) - 1 if mod(ano, 5) == 0
```

However, although Stata generates the new variable, all values are missing.

Alternatively to compounded annual growth rate, I could simply use a growth rate with 2009 and 2006 data. But, the same problem arises - no observations are created.

Comment: Please use `dataex` (in Stata 14.2 or 15.1 up, or `ssc install dataex`) to give examples. Images aren't easy to read or copy.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it using the check-mark.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this toy example:

```
clear

input tina ano Sales
500000069 2006 15000
500000069 2007 17000
500000069 2008 19000
500000069 2009 24000
500000069 2010 22000
500000069 2011 28000
500000069 2012 26000
500000069 2013 29000
500000069 2014 31000
500000069 2015 33000
500000087 2006 40000
500000087 2007 42000
500000087 2008 44000
500000087 2009 46000
500000087 2010 48000
500000087 2011 50000
500000087 2012 52000
500000087 2013 54000
500000087 2014 56000
500000087 2015 58000
end 

format tina %9.0f
```

The following solution:

```
bysort tina: summarize ano

forvalues i = 1 / `= `r(N)' - 3' {
    bysort tina (ano): generate SalesGrowth`i' = (Sales[`i'+3]/Sales[`i'])^(1/3) - 1  
    bysort tina (ano): replace SalesGrowth`i' = . if ano != ano[`i'+3] 
}
```

Gives accurate estimates of what you need:

```
. list

     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |      tina    ano   Sales   SalesG~1   SalesG~2   SalesG~3   SalesG~4   SalesG~5   SalesG~6   SalesG~7 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 500000064   2006   15000          .          .          .          .          .          .          . |
  2. | 500000064   2007   17000          .          .          .          .          .          .          . |
  3. | 500000064   2008   19000          .          .          .          .          .          .          . |
  4. | 500000064   2009   24000   .1696071          .          .          .          .          .          . |
  5. | 500000064   2010   22000          .   .0897442          .          .          .          .          . |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. | 500000064   2011   28000          .          .   .1379805          .          .          .          . |
  7. | 500000064   2012   26000          .          .          .     .02704          .          .          . |
  8. | 500000064   2013   29000          .          .          .          .   .0964574          .          . |
  9. | 500000064   2014   31000          .          .          .          .          .   .0345097          . |
 10. | 500000064   2015   33000          .          .          .          .          .          .   .0827134 |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 11. | 500000096   2006   40000          .          .          .          .          .          .          . |
 12. | 500000096   2007   42000          .          .          .          .          .          .          . |
 13. | 500000096   2008   44000          .          .          .          .          .          .          . |
 14. | 500000096   2009   46000   .0476896          .          .          .          .          .          . |
 15. | 500000096   2010   48000          .   .0455159          .          .          .          .          . |
     |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 16. | 500000096   2011   50000          .          .    .043532          .          .          .          . |
 17. | 500000096   2012   52000          .          .          .    .041714          .          .          . |
 18. | 500000096   2013   54000          .          .          .          .   .0400419          .          . |
 19. | 500000096   2014   56000          .          .          .          .          .   .0384988          . |
 20. | 500000096   2015   58000          .          .          .          .          .          .   .0370703 |
     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```